# Recharts fix x axis to y axis value zero and hide x axis line show values

Tags: reactjs, recharts

currently, I'm getting this graph

[image]

I want it to be like this

[image]

> x-axis on y value zero and display the x-axis values without the line
> as in the above image

this is my source code

```
              <ComposedChart
                data={data}
                margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 15 }}
                stackOffset="sign"
              >
                <XAxis
                  tick={{ fontSize: 12 }}
                  angle={-45}
                  textAnchor="end"
                  interval={0}
                  type="category"
                  dataKey="date"
                  width={5}
                />

                <YAxis
                  label={{
                    value: "Number of subscriber",
                    position: "left",
                    angle: -90,
                    // fontSize: 10,
                    dy: -47,
                  }}
                  tickFormatter={graphTickFormat}
                  type="number"
                />

               
                <Bar dataKey="newSubs" stackId="a" fill="#37aff7" />
                <Bar dataKey="churnSubs" stackId="a" fill="#ffa613" />
                <Line type="monotone" dataKey="netSubGrowth" stroke="#000000" />
              </ComposedChart>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to hide the `XAxis` and use a `ReferenceLine` for `y=0`.
So, `tickLine={false}` on `XAxis` and a `ReferenceLine`

```
          <ComposedChart
            data={data}
            margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, left: 20, bottom: 15 }}
            stackOffset="sign"
          >
            <XAxis
              tickLine={false}
              tick={{ fontSize: 12 }}
              angle={-45}
              textAnchor="end"
              interval={0}
              type="category"
              dataKey="date"
              width={5}
            />
            <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke="#000000" />
            <YAxis
              label={{
                value: "Number of subscriber",
                position: "left",
                angle: -90,
                // fontSize: 10,
                dy: -47,
              }}
              tickFormatter={graphTickFormat}
              type="number"
            />

           
            <Bar dataKey="newSubs" stackId="a" fill="#37aff7" />
            <Bar dataKey="churnSubs" stackId="a" fill="#ffa613" />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="netSubGrowth" stroke="#000000" />
          </ComposedChart>
```

Comment: try `axisLine={false}` instead of `tickLine={false}`